# im trying to include a counter variable inside the loop

Tags: java, loops

java program called product that prompts the user to enter names of hardware devices. The program includes a sentinel loop with a value of ### that stops the input from the user. include a counter variable called inputNum inside the loop, that counts the number of hardware devices the user entered. using a system statement inside the loop, display the names of hardware devices the user entered, include a dialog box outside the loop that displays the counter variable value (number of hardware device names entered by the user)

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: Post your source code with minimal explanation rather than a long story. Also, you have not specified (query) what you are expecting from others?

Answer (score 1):

```
int counter = 0;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


while(true)
{
    System.out.print("Enter the name of a hardware device: ");
    String s = input.next();

    if(!s.equals(null)) counter++;
    if(s.equals("###")) break;
}
```